# Why does Socket.BeginAccept() work in Windows XP but Microsoft says otherwise?

Tags: c#, windows

I was implementing some socket operation on a project and stumbled on `Socket.BeginAccept()` which I found handy and used happily without even checking its official documentation for supported platforms. However, it was after deployment that I learnt that [Windows XP is not included in the list of platforms supported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5bb431f9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) by this function. Yet it works perfectly on it.

Compare this to `Thread.Join()` that is said to support [SP3 of Windows XP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.join%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and thus you simply get a nice system hang for almost 60 secs if you do `Thread.Join()` on Windows XP < SP3. This show that the `Thread.Join()` method follows its documented platform specification while `Socket.BeginAccept()` does not (because the later works on Windows XP >= SP2 while its official documentation does not even support Windows XP at all).

Now I am confused as to what is/is not supported by Windows XP.

Comment: ask Microsoft :) however vendors usually commit to support only scenarios they tested themselves.

Comment: Then they better get more hands on desk and sure to check every code they write on every platform they build...or maybe they are short-staffed :)

Comment: Consider intentions before drawing conclusions about what's off-topic or not. Your point: ***a problem that can no longer be reproduced*** and I will ask that did you take time to confirm that the Join() method works on Win XP while not officially documented so? (Thanks to Hans Passant for giving the best answer for this) so others checking this thread in the future know what is what as regards this no-longer-supported OS (Win XP). I also think not to reword the question title to something like "Now Win XP is out: what happens to our old code?" because that, I think, is way too broad. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You linked to the .NET 4.5 version of the documentation.  A .NET version that is not available for XP, 4.0 is the last one that can still run on XP or Server2003.  Use the version selector at the top of the MSDN article, you'll see that the [4.0 version of the same article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5bb431f9%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) **does** list XP and 2003.

MSDN does have occasional mistakes, but this is not one of them.

Answer (score 2):

Dude, seriously?

Microsoft stopped supporting Windows XP on April 8, 2014 (and that was after extending the support period at least once).

They're not going to take time away from other projects, just to test and document whether an API is supported on a platform where, by definition, *nothing* is supported. Even if that documentation did exist in the past, maintaining it has costs. The platform is unsupported; Microsoft is under no obligation to keep that documentation online forever.

If you choose to run an unsupported OS, then you don't get bugfixes, you don't get security patches, you don't get guarantees that newer software will work, and you don't get a guarantee of accurate documentation. That's what "unsupported" means: it *may* still work, but if you choose to use it, you're on your own.

XP is *dead,* man. Do your grieving and move on.

Comment: Come on! This is not about me grieving dude, it's about end-users. Most clients just don't understand what you mean by saying the good old crap they bought is now "not supported". I don't use XP, but I  develop apps for Windows OS...so when XP is out, I'm concerned about users that still use it (they tell you they like XP because all printers are plug-n-play with XP...other Windows will need drivers)

Comment: ...and if you get the point of my question, the confusing thing is that Thread.Join() still officially states that it supports Windows XP.

Comment: @emmanuel: most documentation written before XP came out of support will still include it.  It isn't as though they've gone through and purged every mention of it; but material that has been updated since then for any other reason may (or may not) have references to XP.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking at the documentation for .NET 4.5, which [never supported Windows XP](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=.NET_Framework_version_history&oldid=508022786#.NET_Framework_4.5).  Windows XP was still in support when .NET 4.5 was released, but .NET 4.5 required Windows Vista or later.

If you use the drop-down menu to look at the [corresponding page for .NET 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5bb431f9(v=vs.100).aspx), XP is listed as supported.

However, as Joe rightly pointed out in his answer, there is no guarantee that any particular piece of documentation will still contain information about Windows XP support.  In this case it still does, but it might be removed in future if that page is updated for some other reason.